# Trying to pass a value from a service to a component in Angula2. Getting: "Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters."

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to pass a specific value from a service to my component. But, I am getting this error in my console:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't resolve all parameters for Help:
>   (?). ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Can't resolve
>   all parameters for Help: (?).
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata

Here is what I have in my service:

```
export class Help{

    good: number;

    constructor (private _uploadedFile: UploadedFile){}

    getGood(){
        this.good = this._uploadedFile.status;
        return this.good;
    }

}
```

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'ocr/templates/image-upload.html',
    providers: [Help]

})


export class OCRComponent {

    statusFromServer: number;

    constructor(private router: Router, @Inject(Help) private _help: Help){}

    options: Object = {
        url: 'http://10.10.10.15:8081/upload'
    };
    sizeLimit = 2000000;

    handleUpload(): void {

        this.statusFromServer = this._help.getGood();
        console.log('this.statusFromServer');

            }

    beforeUpload(uploadingFile): void {
        if (uploadingFile.size > this.sizeLimit) {
            uploadingFile.setAbort();
            alert('File is too large');
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the UploadedFile class from the service:

```
@Injectable()
export class UploadedFile {
    id: string;
    public status: number;
    statusText: string;
    progress: Object;
    originalName: string;
    size: number;
    response: string;
    done: boolean;
    error: boolean;
    abort: boolean;
    startTime: number;
    endTime: number;
    speedAverage: number;
    speedAverageHumanized: string;

    constructor(id: string, originalName: string, size: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.originalName = originalName;
        this.size = size;
        this.progress = {
            loaded: 0,
            total: 0,
            percent: 0,
            speed: 0,
            speedHumanized: null
        };
        this.done = false;
        this.error = false;
        this.abort = false;
        this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.endTime = 0;
        this.speedAverage = 0;
        this.speedAverageHumanized = null;
    }

    setProgres(progress: Object): void {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    setError(): void {
        this.error = true;
        this.done = true;
    }

    setAbort(): void {
        this.abort = true;
        this.done = true;
    }

    onFinished(status: number, statusText: string, response: string): void {
        this.endTime = new Date().getTime();
        this.speedAverage = this.size / (this.endTime - this.startTime) * 1000;
        this.speedAverage = parseInt(<any>this.speedAverage, 10);
        this.speedAverageHumanized = humanizeBytes(this.speedAverage);
        this.status = status;
        this.statusText = statusText;
        this.response = response;
        this.done = true;
        // console.log(status);
        // console.log(response.toString());

    }


}
```

What is wrong with my dependency injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with your UploadFile service, add it as a provider on your component or if you want add it as a provider of your module.

If you add the UploadFile service to your module, that service will be the same instance in every place that you inject it.

Otherwise if you add the UploadFile service on your component that service will be a new instance so some value will be empty if you try to get some values from another component.

Remember to add the `@Injectable()` decorator when you want to make something **injectable**

For more information about DI go to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'ocr/templates/image-upload.html',
    providers: [Help, UploadFile]

})

export class OCRComponent {
   // Removed the content to focus only on the @Component decorator.
}
```

Edit:

After the post of the UploadFile, we saw that it is just a class and the problem was that angular cannot resolve that constructor.

Comment: I just tried the thing you mentioned. Imported the class at the top, and added it in the providers. Didn't help. @camaron

Comment: @TanvirHKShuvo did you added the @Injectable() decorator to both services?

Comment: I just did and now getting: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for String!

Comment: that is fine, check the parameters of the constructors to see if you have a "String" type, it should be just "string".

Comment: I found String nowhere! Should I edit the question and add the UploadedFile service for you to check?

Comment: Yes, please add the UploadFile service.

Comment: I edited the question. Please check the UploadedFile class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131154/discussion-between-camaron-and-tanvir-hk-shuvo).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable() // <<=
export class Help{
```

```
constructor(private router: Router, Help private _help: Help){}
```

This constructor won't work for injectables:

```
constructor(id: string, originalName: string, size: number) {
```

`string` can't be injected.

Either you use

```
    constructor(
      @Inject('someProviderKey1') id: string, 
      @Inject('someProviderKey2') originalName: string,            
      @Inject('someProviderKey3') size: number) {
```

where `someProviderKeyX` needs to be the key of a registered provider
or remove the parameters

and `Help` and `UploadFile` need to be provided somewhere like explained by @camaron

Comment: What do you mean by someProviderKey ? This is within a service. How can I add a provider to a service?

Comment: You can't add a provider to a service, but providers added to `@NgModule()` are available to services as well. `@NgModule({ providers: [{provide: 'someProviderKey1', useValue: 'foo'}], ... })`

Comment: Isn't Help private _help: Help is wrong? Should not I write: @Inject(Help) private _help: Help ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. `private`, `public`, or no modifier doesn't make a difference for DI, it only makes a difference how the injected value will be made avialable in the class independent of it was injected or passed in by `new MyService(null, new Help())`. `@Inject(T)` is not necessary if `T` is the same type the provider was registered with and `T` has an `@Injectable() decorator.